# monacaにて他のインストールされているアプリケーションの起動方法について

Tags: monaca, cordova

monacaを使ってハイブリッドアプリケーションの開発を行っています．
Andriod内で，他にインストールされているアプリケーションを起動したいのですが，うまくいきません．
WebIntentプラグインを用いて，以下のようなものを試してみました．
urlを`package:/data/app/package.apk`にした場合でもうまくいきませんでした．

```
window.plugins.webintent.startActivity({
    action: window.plugins.webintent.ACTION_VIEW,
    url: 'package://package_name'
},
function() {},
function() {alert('Failed to open URL via Android Intent')}
)}
```

monacaでインストールされている他のアプリケーションを起動する方法はないでしょうか．よろしくお願いします．